# Acomodar una matriz en java

Tags: java

Buenas estoy trabajando en un proyecto, que me pide hacer un parqueo con una matriz a la hora que el se eliga un lugar de la matriz esta se debe poner con una X , lo cual significa que ese lugar esta ocupado y ya no se podra usar mas, pero a la hora de poner la X en la matriz se me corren todos los lugares y no entiendo por que. por debajo de la matriz estoy guardando una arraylist con los datos que se ingresan no se si eso sera el problema.
Adjunto codigo

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Borrador2 {
    public static String letras[] = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
    public static ArrayList[][] mente = new ArrayList[10][5];
    public static Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        genMatriz();
        mostrarMatriz();
        registro();
        
  
    
    }
    
    static void genMatriz(){   
        for(int i = 0; i < mente.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mente[i].length; j++){
                String letra = letras[j];
                String letranum = letra + (i+1);
                ArrayList carro = new ArrayList<String>();
                carro.add(letranum);
                carro.add(" ");
                mente[i][j] = carro;
            }
        }
        
    }
    static void mostrarMatriz(){   
        //Mostrar datos de la matriz
        for(int i = 0; i < mente.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mente[i].length; j++){
                if(mente[i][j].get(1) != " "){
                    System.out.println("X|");
                }else{
                     System.out.print(mente[i][j].get(0) + " |");
                    
                }
                }
            System.out.println();   // Imprime salto de línea
        }
   } 
    
    static void registro(){
        String placa,lugar;
        int hora,semana,dia,fecha;
       
        ArrayList carro = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese lugar"); lugar=leer.next();
        carro.add(lugar);
        System.out.println("Ingrese placa"); placa=leer.next();
        carro.add(placa); //1
        System.out.println("Ingrese hora"); hora=leer.nextInt();
        carro.add(hora);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < mente.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mente[i].length; j++){
                if (lugar.equals(mente[i][j].get(0))){
                    x=i;
                    y=j;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        carro.set(1,placa);
        carro.add(hora);
        mente[x][y] = carro;
        
        System.out.println(mente[x][y]);
        mostrarMatriz();

    }
}
```

si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria demaciado.

Comment: debe ser por que estas imprimiendo con salto de linea  `System.out.println("X|");` reemplazalo por  `System.out.print(" X| ");`

Comment: gracias era eso!